# SharePoint : are programmatic copy/move operations on folders and document sets guaranteed to be atomic?

Tags: sharepoint

Just wondering if programmatic operations in SharePoint that allow moving or copying folders (and their content) and document sets (and their content) are guaranteed to be atomic, so they fail or succeed as a whole ?

Examples of calls are `SPFolder.Copy`, `DocumentSet.Import`, `SP.MoveCopyUtil`, `CreateCopyJobs`, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checked the code, copy of a folder for example is really done in a loop with some cleanup logic in case of a failure which might fail itself leaving a dirty thing.

Answer (score 0):

I think so, they should be atmoic so they fail or succeed as a whole.